# GitLab Ci/CD job is pending even though Group runner is available

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have created a fresh setup of GitLab with GCP integration in the “infrastructure as code” way.

I have a separate project for cluster management with the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and `helmfile.yml`:

```
helmDefaults:
  atomic: true
  wait: true

helmfiles:
 - path: applications/gitlab-runner/helmfile.yaml
```

and runner settings are these:

```
gitlabUrl: "https://gitlab.com/"
runnerRegistrationToken: "oneoneone"
concurrent: 4
checkInterval: 3
rbac:
  create: true
  clusterWideAccess: false
runners:
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  builds: {}
  services: {}
  helpers: {}
  tags: kubernetes,cluster
  privileged: true
resources: {}
```

Basically, I haven't changed anything in the default “Cluster Management Project Template” other than uncommenting needed applications.

I can see my runner in among the running pods.

```
~ kubectl get pods --namespace=gitlab-managed-apps
NAME                                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-ingress-controller-68bcfdf674-n676q      1/1     Running   0          32m
ingress-nginx-ingress-default-backend-c9b59c85-5mqmt   1/1     Running   0          32m
runner-gitlab-runner-7bc56b9b7c-vkbsx                  1/1     Running   0          32m
```

I can see this runner among these `Group -> CI/CD -> Runners`:
[image]

I can also see this runner in group runners when I go to the project CI/CD settings:
[image]

But for some reason, when I start the pipeline, it hangs in a “pending” state and never spins.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this group runner accept jobs from group projects?

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?  I have encountered the exact same issue as you just now.

Comment: well, I just reinstalled the whole setup, including the cluster and it magically started. good that I wasn't that far in my development yet

Comment: Ohh great.  For me it was due to configuration on the runner.  I raised an issue with GitLab itself: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/337905#note_646414227